# Latest Opencart Full Product path

Tags: search, opencart, opencart2.3

How do I get the full product path when clicking it from latest module or search results, let me explain a bit more:

breadcrumbs are Home > Product Name instead of Home > Category > Product Name

The products listed in the latest module. When I click on one of them it takes me to the product page without the category id and it does the same for the search.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. However, you can use $product['href']

Comment: Try this: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=19162&filter_category_id=19&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=37&sort=date_modified